# Clear timeout at start of function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

http://jsfiddle.net/yhXum/4/

When you press start, the box will move to a new position every two seconds, but if you keep pressing the button, the:

```
setTimeout("random()", 2000);
```

will stack up making the box move like crazy.

How do I make it so that it resets every time the function is called?

The reason this is a duplicate question is because I've just started learning and I really need someone to just do it for me, as I don't really know how to implement answers from similar questions.

Comment: It's generally considered good practice to use `setTimeout(random, 2000)` instead of `setTimeout("random()", 2000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use clearTimeout. However, my suggestion would be to hide the start button. If you're actually putting this in a website, this will make more sense to your users as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/g3heA/

For the stop button, you can use a variable called `interval` to keep track of the interval id and clear it later.

```
function start() {
    // Hide the start button
    document.querySelector("#start").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#stop").style.display = "block";
    random();
}

function stop() {
    clearTimeout(interval);
    document.querySelector("#stop").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#start").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout):

```
var myTimeout;
function random()
{
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    x = (x * 10);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    y = (y * 10);

    document.getElementById("box").style.left = x + "px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.top = y + "px";

    myTimeout = setTimeout("random()", 2000);    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhXum/5/

Answer (score 0):

check this
[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yhXum/6/) without timeout

```
var flag=true;
function random()
{
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
x = (x * 10);
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
y = (y * 10);

document.getElementById("box").style.left = x + "px";
document.getElementById("box").style.top = y + "px";
    if(flag){
        setTimeout(random, 2000);
        flag=false;
    }

}
```